# Django: form is not displaying

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

After the user registers, I am using signals to create a user profile, so they can fill in additional details (like country or website) that the standard registration form can't offer. The problem is the form is not displaying the contents. However I can fill in the same form on admin site easily, but I want to allow users to do it by themselves.

On Chrome I tried to inspect the problem, and where there is a form it says input='hidden'. What might be the problem?
Thank you in advance.

**my views:**

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
     edit_form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, 
     instance=request.user.profile)

      if edit_form.is_valid():
        edit_form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Your account has been updated!')
        return redirect(profile)
    else:
      edit_form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
context = {'edit_form': edit_form}
return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

**my profile.html:**

```
<form method='POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ edit_form }}
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

**models:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
  country = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
  website = models.URLField(default='')
  image = models.ImageField(default='images/profile.jpg', 
  upload_to='images')

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
  if kwargs['created']:
    profile = Profile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ('status', 'website', 'description', 'country', 'user', )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get an indentation error when you run your code?
If not can you please update your question with the correct indentation so that the SO people can help you troubleshoot.

Next up, do you have any group permissions in place for standard users vs non-standard user(admin)? I would check to see if they have the capability to modify their User objects freely.

Errors for the form are usually displayed by `<ul class="errorlist">` [FormsAPI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#how-errors-are-displayed), I would check for those. If none, then I would double check that the form being returned isn't actually blank by debugging it and looking at the `__dict__` definition of that object. I can't give you any more suggestions until the indentation part is fixed so I can rule out any logic errors.

Found the problem: `edit_form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)`

What you want to do is query the `Profile` object that belongs to the user, **bold** then pass it in as an instance to your `EditProfileForm`.

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('status', 'website', 'description', 'country', 'user', )
```

Your form's Meta is the `Profile` object not the `User` object.

Hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: Sorry about indentation. Pasted and did not review. Anyway, will check on permissions, didn't cross my mind, so cheers for that.

Comment: @EgidijusJančaitis no prob, I added more to my answer, you were passing and instance of your user vs an instance of your model.

Comment: thanks a lot for the advice, will try to apply it and review. Been killing myself fr ages, so much appreciated

Comment: All good dude, I know all too well how that feels like. If it works for you, please remember to mark my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Will do, mate. no worries